# BLtoolkit association

Tags: database, entity, bltoolkit

i have this entity:

```
namespace Entities.dbo
{
    [TableName("tbl_question")]
    public class Question : AbstractEntity
    {
        [MapField("c_from")]
        [Association(CanBeNull = false, OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "c_from")]
        public User From { get; set; }

        [MapField("c_to")]
        [Association(CanBeNull = false, OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "c_to")]
        public Band To { get; set; }

    }
}
```

leading to a Band entity :

```
namespace Entities.dbo
{
    [TableName("tbl_band")]
    public class Band : AbstractEntity
    {
        [MapField("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MapField("frontman")]
        [Association(CanBeNull = false, ThisKey = "frontman", OtherKey = "id")]
        public User Frontman { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but when I try to get questions like :

```
public static List<Question> GetQuestions(Band band)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbManager())
            {
                try
                {

                    var l = db.GetTable<Question>().Where(x => x.To == band).ToList();

                    return l;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                    return null; 
                }
            }
```

I got this exception:

```
Association key 'c_to' not found for type 'Entities.dbo.Question.
```

any idea wheres the problem ?

I know that in the table tbl_question is column c_to..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ThisKey property represents key fields (comma delimited) on the side where the association is defined. The field of entity class, not database table field!
In your case, you must:

```
1. Define field in the Question entity for ThisKey property:

[MapField("c_to")]
public int BandId { get; set; }

2. Define field in the Band entity for OtherKey property:

[MapField("id")]
public string BandId { get; set; }

3. Rewrite To property in the Question entity:

[Association(CanBeNull = false, OtherKey = "BandId", ThisKey = "BandId")]
public Band To { get; set; }
```